# Java JFrame: Image not displayed

Tags: java, image, awt, jframe

Im trying to build a small frame that displays an image.

My problem is that in the `paint(Graphics g)` method, the `g.drawImage` is executed, but nothing is shown on my RLFrame.

Any thoughts / tips?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code

```
public class RLFrame extends JFrame{

 Image img;
 public RLFrame(String title){
  super("testing");
 }
 public  void run(){
  MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setSize(400, 400);

  this.img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("maps/23bis.ppm");
  mt.addImage(this.img, 1, 100, 100);
  this.setVisible(true);
 }


 public void paint(Graphics g){
  System.out.println("Paint");
     if(img != null){
      System.out.println("draw");
       g.drawImage(img, 300,  300, this);
     }
     else
     {
       g.clearRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
     }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead of `paint(Graphics g)` in your code. Something like

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Paint");
        if (img != null) {
            System.out.println("draw");
            g.drawImage(img, 300, 300, this);
        }
        else
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
 }
```

Add the image to a JPanel, then add that JPanel instance to your RLFrame.

Comment: still nothing. Its not even executed :(

Answer (score 1):

You should never overrid the paint() method of a JFrame.

There is no need for you to do custom painting. Just create an ImageIcon and add it to a JLabel, then add the label to the frame.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html). If you really need to do custom painting then the tutorial also has a section on custom painting.